# Best way to pass data to dependent select field in two different components

Tags: reactjs, next.js, formik

Apologies for all the questions of late, but our volunteer mission is in Dec and I have a lot to do, and these initial questions will help me complete the rest of the work!

Now I'm looking for the best way to populate a select field, based on an API response after an initial select field is chosen.

In the image below, what I am trying to accomplish is once a user selects a `Province`, I want to pass the chosen `prov_id` to another Component to make the API call to my MongoDB and retrieve the associated Districts based on the chosen province.

Each of these two Selects are separate Components, as I will need them in other areas of forms for the patient platform I'm building. 
**Province** Select is in `displayProvinces.js` 
**District** Select is in `displayDistricts.js`

[image]

I do have the Province Select working, and it I was able to call the District API, while I had them as one component, but now that I want to separate these into sub-components, I'm looking for the best way to pass the `prov_id` from `displayProvinces.js` over to `displayDistricts.js` so I can make the API call and populate the Districts select options.

Content of

```js
import {React, useMemo} from 'react';
import GetProvincesAPI from '@/utils/services/GetProvincesAPI';
import {Field, useFormikContext } from 'formik';
import {useTranslation} from 'react-i18next';

export default function DisplayProvinces(props){
  
  const [ provinces ] = GetProvincesAPI();
  const {setFieldValue, errors, touched} = useFormikContext();
  const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();
  
  function handleSelectedProvince(pr){
    console.log('Fired')
    console.log('Selected Province = ' +pr)
    // Want to send 'pr' to displayDistricts.js in order to pull the appropriate Districts
  }
  
  return (
    <>
      <Field
        as="select"
        id="pxProvince"
        name="pxProvince"
        onChange={(e)=> {
          handleSelectedProvince(e.target.value)
          setFieldValue('pxProvince', e.target.value)
        }}
        className="mt-1 block w-full pl-3 pr-10 py-2 text-base border-gray-300 focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 sm:text-sm rounded-md"
      >
        {!provinces ? provinces : provinces.map((p, i) => (
          <option key={i} value={p.prov_id}>{p.prov_name}</option>
        ))}
      </Field>
      {props.onError &&
        <p className="mt-2 text-sm text-red-600" id="pxnum-error">
          {t('forms.rego.fields.px.provinceError')}
        </p>
      }
    </>
  )
}
```

Contents of displayDistricts.js

```js
/* eslint-disable react-hooks/rules-of-hooks */
/* TODO: Fix the hook useProvinces inside the useMemo in order to have proper code */
import {Field, useFormikContext} from 'formik';
import GetDistrictsAPI from '@/utils/services/GetDistrictsAPI';
import {useMemo} from 'react';

export default function DisplayDistricts(props) {
  
  const {setFieldValue, values} = useFormikContext();
  const handleSelectedDistrict = useMemo(() => getDistricts(), []);
  
  let districts = [
    { id: '0', name: 'Select a Province first' }
  ]
  
  function getDistricts(d) {
    let districts = GetDistrictsAPI(d);
    console.log(districts)
  
    function handleSelectedDistrict(pr) {
      console.log('Selected District = ' +pr)
    }
  
    return handleSelectedDistrict;
  }
  
  return (
    <Field
      as="select"
      id="pxDistrict"
      name="pxDistrict"
      disabled={!values.pxProvince}
      className="mt-1 block w-full pl-3 pr-10 py-2 text-base border-gray-300 focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 sm:text-sm rounded-md"
    >
      {!districts ? districts : districts.map((p, i) => (
        <option key={i} value={p.dist_id}>{p.name}</option>
      ))}
    </Field>
  )
}
```

Thanks in advance for any insight/thoughts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this solution, check comment :

Main component

```
function Main() {
    const [province, setProvince] = useState({id: "" , name: ""});
    const [districts, setDistricts] = useState({});

\\ when select province you have id for other component 
console.log(province)
\\ so you can pass id DisplayDistricts component

    return (
        <>
            <DisplayProvinces callback={(e) => setProvince({id: e.id , name: i.name})} />
            <DisplayDistricts idProvince={province.id} callback={(e) => setDistricts({id: e.id , name: i.name})} />
        </>
    )
}
```

Content of

```
export default function DisplayProvinces(props){
  
  const [ provinces ] = GetProvincesAPI();
  const {setFieldValue, errors, touched} = useFormikContext();
  const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();
function handleSelectedProvince(name , id){
    console.log('Fired')
    console.log('Selected Province = ' +pr)
    props.callback({id: id , name:name})
    // Want to send 'pr' to displayDistricts.js in order to pull the appropriate Districts
  }
  
  return (
    <>
      <Field
        as="select"
        id="pxProvince"
        name="pxProvince"
        onChange={(e)=> {
          handleSelectedProvince(e.target.value , e.target[e.target.selectedIndex].id)
          setFieldValue('pxProvince', e.target.value)
        }}
        className="mt-1 block w-full pl-3 pr-10 py-2 text-base border-gray-300 focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 sm:text-sm rounded-md"
      >
        {!provinces ? provinces : provinces.map((p, i) => (
          <option key={i} id={p.prov_id} value={p.prov_name}>{p.prov_name}</option>
        ))}
      </Field>
      {props.onError &&
        <p className="mt-2 text-sm text-red-600" id="pxnum-error">
          {t('forms.rego.fields.px.provinceError')}
        </p>
      }
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks @H9ee, this does indeed work! Just need to sort the rest, cheers mate!

Comment: your welcome bro, and good luck